# ререндер компонента при обновлении данных на сервере

Tags: reactjs, redux

Не могу реализовать ререндер компонента при изменении данных на сервере.
подключил redux,создал редюсмер, экшен, контейнер покинул пропсы. Store в целевой компонент попадает в том виде в котором должен туда попасть.
При изменении данных (несколько функций которые меняют данные на сервере) (Store изменяется только вызовом функции которая загружает данные с сервера) не происходит ререндер компонента.
на что обратить внимание?

Comment: Для начала было бы не плохо увидеть ваши наработки, а дальше отталкиваясь от вашего кода давать советы и ответы.

Comment: REDUCER  https://pastebin.com/XHt2jXVC

Comment: ACTION https://pastebin.com/VJcWsgmU

Comment: CONTAINER https://pastebin.com/4tu25Dkw

Comment: COMBINE REDUCER https://pastebin.com/gPwgpnuJ

Comment: CREATE STORE https://pastebin.com/GaEywxxc

Comment: COMPONENT https://pastebin.com/XLkHANyd

Comment: в компоненте не стал выкладывать рендер

Comment: Ну, начну с нескольких моментов, которые нужно переписать. Первое, зачем в `cityContainer` вы использовали redux, если исходя из вашего кода он должен быть в `Cities`, вы просто затянули методы и данные и передали их дальше, не нужно так делать. Переносите `connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)` в `Cities` и убирайте методы `componentDidUpdate` и `componentWillMount` из этого компонента совсем. Далее совет на будущее, не используйте `componentWillMount`, он устарел, вместо него нужно юзать `componentDidMount`. Уберите `async/await`, и не вешайте больше на метод `setState` ожидание.

Comment: Ну что, заработал ререндер должным образом? Или сайд эффект до сих пор наблюдается?

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, каджый ваш тип редьюсера обрабатывается одинаково, независимо какой тип вы диспатчите, вы всегда передаете в редьюсер массив. Это не совсем правильно. Если вы диспатчите удаление, добавление, редактирование элемента, лучше передавать в редьюсер сам элемент, а не готовый массив. Соответсвенно, к примеру, добавление должно выглядеть так:

```
case ADD_CITY:
    return {
        ...state,
        cities: [...state.cities, action.city] // Обязательно передавайте новый массив, чтобы произошел ре-рендер(cities сам по себе никак не изменится если вы в него сделаете push, а потом вернете его же)
    }
```

Во-вторых, mapDispatchToProps у вас вообще не функция, вы никак не используете сам Dispatch. Вы просто пробрасываете методы, которые возвращают объект. mapDispatchToProps должен выглядеть примерно следубщим образом

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    AddCity: () => dispatch(AddCity()),
    // И так далее с каждым вашим методом
})
```